# Time Signature Translation

Tags: theory

I need to change a simple piece from 9/8 to 9/4. Do I only need to double the values for each note? (Ex. quarter to half note & eighth to quarter?) And what would I do to change a dotted quarter in 9/8 to 9/4?

Comment: The answer is the exact same as your other question.

Comment: What about for dotted notes? (I'm quite new to this, I'm sorry)

Comment: Double the value which will typically be the note value above it dotted. A dotted not adds half the vale of the note.

Comment: you only just asked this exact question....

Answer (score 0):

A dotted note doubled is the same as a regular note doubled it just retains its dot.

So in essence a crotchet doubled is a minim and a dotted crotchet doubled is a dotted minim.

[image: Doubling of a note without a dot]

[image: Doubling of a note with a dot.]

So in compound time if you want to go dotted crotchet beats to dotted minim beats the quavers will become crotchets. crotchets minims and if anything has a dot it become the note doubled with a dot.